# can not use resultSet.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE) with spring jdbc DaoSupport with Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, resultset, spring-jdbc, scrollableresults

I want to use scrollable resultset, so when I use two lines of code:

```
 rs.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
rs.absolute(12);
```

in my DAOimpl, I get exception, plz help to solve them, thank in advance.

```
 import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCallback;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Component
    public class MyDAOimpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements
            MyDAO {

        public List<User> getList(final String where) throws Exception {

            return (List) getJdbcTemplate().execute(
                    "{call PKG_USER.getUser(?,?)}",
                    new CallableStatementCallback() {
                        public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                                throws SQLException {

                            cs.setString(1, where);
                            cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
                            cs.execute();

                            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(6);

                            rs.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
                            rs.absolute(12);

                            List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

                            while (rs.next()) {

                                User user = new User(
                                        rs.getString(1),
                                        rs.getString(2), 
                                        rs.getString(3));
                                list.add(user);
                            }
                            return list;
                        }
                    });

        }
    }
```

this is exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call: setFetchDirection
    oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.BaseResultSet.setFetchDirection(BaseResultSet.java:128)
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

where I change like the following, I didn't get any result, normally, my procedure return 100 users:

```
return (List) getJdbcTemplate().execute(new CallableStatementCreator() {

            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(
                    Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                return connection.prepareCall(
                        "{call PKG_USER.getUser(?,?)}",
                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
            }
        }, new CallableStatementCallback() {

            public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

                cs.setString(1, where);
                cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
                cs.execute();

                ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(6);

                //////not run////
                rs.absolute(12);
                ////////////////

                List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

                while (rs.next()) 
                {   
                    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

                            while (rs.next()) {

                                User user = new User(
                                        rs.getString(1),
                                        rs.getString(2), 
                                        rs.getString(3));
                                list.add(user);
                            }
                            return list;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

First, `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` is a constant indicating a *result set type* and is certainly not a valid argument for `setFetchDirection` which expects a *fecth direction*. Quoting the parameter section of the javadoc of [`ResultSet#setFetchDirection(int direction)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchDirection%28int%29):

> `direction` - an `int` specifying the suggested fetch direction; one of `ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD`, `ResultSet.FETCH_REVERSE`, or `ResultSet.FETCH_UNKNOWN`

Hence the exception and the message "Invalid argument(s) in call: `setFetchDirection`".

And BTW, according to Oracle's "[JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/toc.htm)" (all versions are available from http://tahiti.oracle.com/) in [Processing a Scrollable Result Set](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/resltset.htm#sthref1169):

> #### Presetting the Fetch Direction
>
> The JDBC 2.0 standard allows the
>   ability to pre-specify the direction,
>   known as the fetch direction, for use
>   in processing a result set. This
>   allows the JDBC driver to optimize its
>   processing. The following result set
>   methods are specified:
>
> - `void setFetchDirection(int
>     direction) throws SQLException`  *
>     `int getFetchDirection() throws
>     SQLException`
>
> The Oracle JDBC drivers **support only
>   the forward preset value**, which you
>   can specify by inputting the
>   `ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD` static
>   constant value.
>
> The values `ResultSet.FETCH_REVERSE` and
>   `ResultSet.FETCH_UNKNOWN` are not
>   supported. Attempting to specify them
>   causes a SQL warning, and the settings
>   are ignored.

This is also mentioned in the [readme](http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/112/Readme.txt) of the [Oracle Database 11g  Release 2 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_112010.html) (the ultimate version at the time of writing this):

> The scrollable result set
>   implementation has the following
>   limitation:
>
> - setFetchDirection() on ScrollableResultSet does not do
>     anything.

But all this was a kind of side note, using `setFetchDiretion` is simply not the way to get a scrollable result set.

To create a scrollable result set with Spring's `JdbcTemplate`, you should actually use the method [`execute(CallableStatementCreator csc, CallableStatementCallback action)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute(org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCallback)) with a custom [`CallableStatementCreator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/CallableStatementCreator.html) implementation. In this implementation, use the method [`Connection.prepareCall(String sql, int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) to create a `CallableStatement` that will produce `ResultSet` objects with the given type and concurrency. Finally, call `rs.absolute()`.

---

**UPDATE:** There is a problem in the `connection.prepareCall()` call, the third parameter should be a concurrency type (either `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` or `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`). Try this:

```
            return connection.prepareCall(
                    "{call PKG_USER.getUser(?,?)}",
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Comment: plz check my post again, I was change my code, but it not run correctly.
thank you very much.

Comment: after add ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE and ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE to create connection.prepareCall() method, I still get error when use resultSet.absolute(16)
------------------------------------
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [99999]; error code [17075]; Invalid operation for forward only resultset : absolute; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : absolute

Comment: Your callable statement is likely unable to return a scrollable result set: *Invalid operation for **forward only** resultset*. There are indeed some limitation, see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/resltset.htm#sthref1546. Check if you can avoid these limitations or you won't be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get custom ResultSet from jdbc template. Spring has provided a PreparedStatementCreatorFactory from which you can create PreparedStatementCreator.

```
PreparedStatementCreatorFactory pc = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sqlQuery, , new int[] {Types.VARCHAR});//query and params Types
pc.setResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);//TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE 
pc.setUpdatableResults(false);//CONCUR_READ_ONLY

jdbcTemplate.query(pc.newPreparedStatementCreator(listOfParams),
                        myResultSetExtractor);//perform query with custom psc, process results at ResultSetExtractor
```